# Client - Server on Local Wifi delphi XE7 Project VCL

Tags: android, windows, delphi, vcl

At First , i'm using VCL Component , and i don't know if is possible to do this project without FireMonkey Component...(If it's not possible i will use firemonkey component)

My Question is really simple , i'm searching for an example of a project , or for concept , where i can use an application (Client) of Android , to control another one (Server) on PC on a WLAN. I Try now to explain better :

WINDOWS ''Server'' (Because i call server but is normal W8/W10 OS (Application Running)

Ip 192.168.0.1

```
Button1.buttonclick := FrmMain.close
```

ANDROID

Ip 192.168.0.2

```
Connect To Ip of Server (Through WIFI-192.168.0.1)
```

and then

```
 ServerProgram.Button1.click;
```

I try to search on net but i don't find anything for 2 reasons :

1) Probably i don't search for the Most correct solution i need

2) More Probably i don't know as well what i need to search to solve my problem!

So , at first i want to say thanks to all who take time to read , and at least , thanks for help and have a nice day

P.S.

*I DONT WANT TO USE TTHREAD for that because i don't want to intercept them everytime or leave them running!*

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Xe7 for W10 :) Thanks for reply!

Comment: I'd like to recommend you to Pawel Glowacki's introduction videos for Datasnap. [Delphi Labs](https://www.embarcadero.com/rad-in-action/delphi-labs) These will give you an idea of what you need to understand _before_ you can start to program your application.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot , u make my day!

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a command to the PC from your Android device. It is best way to use sockets over TCP/IP. Then you have to "developer" your protocol. That measn that your client must send something like "ButtonClick" string over connected socket. When server receives that command it executes your code (the code you need). It can be simple number (01 - buttons click, 02 - something else). Or string (as above3) or anything else.

The very first thing you have to do is take a look on sockets (on Android and PC side). As I could understand you would like to make it simple and use only VCL/FMX. So take a look on Indy (or something else) that available in Delphi. Good start point is TClientSocket/TServerSocket for desktop applications (there are demos).

Once you find a way to establish a connection (it is not bad idea to work on PC for beginning to understand all the things) you can send your commands using Write (or similar) method to send command. On the server side your application receives an event when command received. Then you process hte command and do what you need.

There should be sample applications for FMX for using Indy (or similar) TCP.IP components. In fact it does not matter how your Android connected youy PC. It can be WLAN, LAN or even Internet. Since your application (client) knows your server IP address or name it can connect to it.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Do you know any TCP/IP Component for FMX? I tried Indy IdTcpClient/Server but not working at all for FMX. Thanks in advance!